# include nonfree openCV 2.4.10 on ubuntu

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, surf

I've installed OpenCV on ubuntu using this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) and I'm trying to use SURF descriptor. I knew that they changed the location of these type of descriptors to the nonfree module so we need to include it, which is something like this: `#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"`. The problem is that I'm getting this error at compile time: `opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp no such file or directory.`

Any idea how to fix it?

**EDITED:**
The other parts of openCV are working fine. I'm including the following libraries and everything is looking good:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp"
```

I checked the inlcude folder in my OpenCV directory and the nonfree folder is there. Moreover, it's the only library that I can't access within QTCreator (The environment I'm using) because I tried to include all the other librairies found in the Inlcude folder and they looked good.

**EDITED2:**
You can see a screenshot of what I saw when I ran `make VERBOSE=1` on this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/if1sabues125je4/3.png?dl=0)

So not sure where to look? Actually, I did not find the nonfree folder in ../usr/include/opencv2/

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>` (use < > instead of " ")

Comment: I tried them both and got same error.

Comment: Run make with `VERBOSE=1" and check whether the right directory is passed.

Comment: You should find the path in the command invoking the compiler after a `-I`. If the path after the -I together with opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp is a valid header, it should work. If this is not the case, copy the part invoking the compiler and add the right -I with the path. If that works, try to add the include path in your CMake appropriately.

Comment: please replace the unreadable image with *text*

Comment: @usr1234567 actually I did not understand exactly what you mean. Can u please clarify?

Comment: if you installed opencv via some ppm, they might have removed the 'nonfree' module. you probably have to build from github src then.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Actually, I just updated openCV using the following commands then it worked:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:xqms/opencv-nonfree
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev
```

Comment: The repository doesn't exist any more: `Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/xqms/opencv-nonfree/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`.

Comment: Still works for m2. AxeEffect please confirm or remove your comment

Comment: @PauloNeves Repository doesn't exist anymore. Doesn't work for me

Comment: This repository working on Ubuntu 16, but not on Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 10):

`sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:xqms/opencv-nonfree`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev`

---this answer works well for me, thanks @Maystro

after this step, just link your program to -lopencv_nonfree, or you cannot access to surf.

Comment: How to link program to -lopencv_nonfree?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:xqms/opencv-nonfree
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:jeff250/opencv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev
```

Here's where I found it:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1141214/689474