# fatal error: opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I have installed Opencv 2.4.8 on my Linux(ubuntu 14.04) machine and it works fine. When I'm trying to test SURF descriptor using sample code from the online official documentation the compiler gave me no such file or director error for `#include<opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>`

.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481849/include-nonfree-opencv-2-4-10-on-ubuntu) link i have tried to update the opencv library for the nonfree modules with but still no success.

To make history short how can include SURF descriptor to my project or any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This was already answered in [opencv surf function is not implemented][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175794/opencv-surf-function-is-not-implemented

Comment: just note, that answer from 2012 might no more be valid in 2015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [include nonfree openCV 2.4.10 on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481849/include-nonfree-opencv-2-4-10-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:xqms/opencv-nonfree
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE` when you build your opencv version.
I guess it goes like this in the prompt command `cmake -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON ..`

But if you prefer cmake GUI see the picture below.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD3Hh.png)